# Closing 1s battery connector

Tags: batteries, connector, wire, drone

I have a drone that can plug two 1s batteries. I have the option the plug only one battery but I need to "close" the other battery input with the following (image).

[image]

I have no idea how this is called. Mine broke and I need to find an other one.

How is this called?
It a 1s battery connector but with a wire that goes from the positive to the negative.

**Edit**

I put a better picture. This is the actual part that just broke. Maybe there's an easy way to fix it.

Comment: The photo is very low resolution. Take a photo of your connector.

Comment: @Transistor good idea, I just updated the image.

Comment: Without measurements and both sides, can't be 100%, but I'm pretty sure that's a standard 2-Pin JST PH connector.

Comment: next time, resist the urge to pull on the wire.

Comment: Can you search how to splice wires or solder to crimp connectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two wire cables with connectors are not easily repairable. The contacts in the connector are special parts that are crimped onto the end of the wire with a special tool. A repair would entail purchasing both the contacts and the crimping tool. This would be horrendously expensive compared to just purchasing some new cables. For LiPo battery applications you can get these types of cables inexpensively from Sparkfun, Adafruit and even on Amazon.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: [https://www.amazon.com/Shappy-Pieces-Connector-Silicone-Female/dp/B07449V33P](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07449V33P))*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is easily repaired. Simply remove the contact where the wire has broken. You do this by gently lifting the plastic tab and pushing the pin out. Practice on the pin that still has the wire attached. I normally use something like a straight pin to push the contact out of the connector housing.

Trim a tiny bit of wire from the broken wire so as to make the end nice and square. Strip perhaps 0.5mm or so insulation from the broken wire. Tin the exposed conductor and leave just the tiniest ball of solder on the end.

Hold the contact that you removed from the connector in a vise or even just an alligator clip. Tin the end of the contact.

Now just solder the broken wire onto the end of the contact.

This repair is not as strong as the crimped connection but is reasonably robust if you take care with your soldering.

[image]